# How to dynamically create an element inside of a div?

Tags: javascript, dynamically-generated, appendchild

Question is above, wondering how to dynamically create an element inside of a div. Right now I have figured out how to dynamically create an element, but it's not inside of any divs, using document.body.appendChild.

Comment: Well, replace the `document.body` part of `document.body.appendChild` with a reference to the div element then?

Comment: element.innerHTML += "additional HTML code"?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a sample code to share so we can help with the problem instead of writing the code for you?

Answer (score 1):

Append it to the element where you want it to be inside of.

```
const parentElement = document.querySelector('.yourParentElement');
parentElement.appendChild(yourDynamicChildElement);
```

Comment: Thank you! I am seeing this solution after I found a solution using insertBefore, but it seems like it's similar. Thanks for this, as I can use it in other parts of my code!

Answer (score 0):

Another way I just found is to use to insertBefore, to insert it before something. I put a p inside of my div where I wanted the element to go, and then it put the p inside of the div in the spot where I wanted my dynamically created element to go. Then, by using insertBefore, it would insert my dynamically created element right before the p, making it go where I wanted it to go.

```
var element = document.createElement("yourElement");//make a var for the dynamically created element that you want to make
        
var parent = document.getElementById("divID");//ID of the <div>
var child = document.getElementById("pID");//ID of the <p> where I want my dynamically created element to go
     
<div>

<p id="pID"></p>
</div>
```